# Why does twilio work in the command prompt but not in IDLE or PyScripter?

Tags: python, pip, twilio, easy-install, pyscripter

I have been trying to the last five hours to install Twilio. It will not work. I used pip and easy_install and they both claimed the installs were successful. Even when I try to use pip to upgrade Twilio, it claims that twilio is already up to date. I can use the follow code...

```
import twilio
print(twilio.__version)
```

... in the command prompt through windows, but not in IDLE or PyScripter will it allow me to import the twilio module. What can I do to fix this?

Based on the comment I received from @juanpa.arrivillaga I changed the interpreter in PyScripter and I got this error when I ran the above code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

from six import u

# Backwards compatibility.
from .version import __version__, __version_info__

from .exceptions import TwilioException, TwimlException

from .rest.exceptions import TwilioRestException


ImportError: No module named six
```

Comment: Probably because it isn't using the right interpreter in IDLE or PyScripter.

Comment: Look, you aren't really giving enough detail to specifically solve your problem. The interpreter you are trying to use does not have those modules installed, that is fundamentally the problem, or at least, something is messed up with your PATH variables.

Comment: If you need to find out which interpreter is the one you need, use your command prompt where you *can* import the modules you want, and use `os.path.dirname(sys.executable)` and see what it tells you.

Comment: All it gave me with print(os.path.dirname(sys.executable)) in the command prompt I could import the module was three dots and no real output. [Screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/8fcbd2d2bb0067e27ab14f96a752aa53.png) @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: You have to `import os, sys` first... And you are getting those three dots because you forgot to a closing parenthesis on `print`... And you don't really need to `print` in an interactive interpreter session.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have gotten PyScripter to recignize twilio. The issue is now when running it, it will send me over to the __init__ for twilio and I continue to get the "No module named 'six'" error as it is trying to "from six import u". I changed the interpreter to Pythonw.exe instead of Python.exe which worked.

Comment: What do you mean the `__init__` for twilio? When you `import twilio`, you get the "No Module named six" error?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga By init I meant that PyScripter opened a new module called __init__.py and then it attempted at running that and it stated there was no module named six. The code for the init script is above in my question.

Comment: Then probably because you don't have `six` installed on that interpreter. Noticing a pattern? I suspect you haven't been careful with how you are installing things, and have modules installed all over the place.